# Looking for a way to grab all Steam header images

Tags: image, screen-scraping, steam

Basically I have been trying to find a nice simple way to automate grabbing lots of steam header images for use as Windows tile icons

All of the headers are stored here

http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/10/header.jpg

With the number being the game's ID

I've seen a bit about scraping, but I am unsure how to do something that basically downloads all images from

/apps/10/header.jpg

to

/apps/500000/header.jpg

And etc

Comment: There is an [api](http://steamcommunity.com/dev) for that.

Answer (score 2):

I built a small script to do this in Python (version 2, but it should run fine in using 3). This utilizes the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, so if you don't have that installed you'd need that too.

#### Set up:

- Copy this script into a file and save with a python extension. Example: `download_headers.py`
- In the same directory that `download_headers.py` was saved, create a directory named `game_headers`

#### Script:

```py
import requests
import os

save_location = "game_headers"

base_url = "http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=%s&filters=basic"

header_images = []
full_path = os.path.abspath(save_location)

for x in [440,65980,281690,1]:
    r = requests.get(base_url % (x)).json()
    try:
        header_images.append((x, r[unicode(x)]['data']['header_image']))
    except KeyError:
        print "AppID {} => Did not return data".format(x)

# Download the images

for i in header_images:
    print "Downloading header image for AppID {}".format(i[0])
    r = requests.get(i[1], stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(os.path.join(full_path, "{}_header.jpg".format(unicode(i[0]))), 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content():
                f.write(chunk)
```

#### Output:

```
> python headers.py
AppID 1 => Did not return data
Downloading header image for AppID 440
Downloading header image for AppID 65980
Downloading header image for AppID 281690
```

And there are now three images in my `game_headers` directory.

#### Modifications

As it is currently written, the script only looks for images for App IDs `440`, `65980`, `281690` and `1`. If you want to make it a full range of IDs, modify the following line:

```py
for x in [440,65980,281690,1]:
```

to be a range of integers:

```py
for x in range(420,450):
```

This will result in a lot of App IDs not existing, but as was seen above with App ID `1`, these are skipped:

```
AppID 421 => Did not return data
AppID 422 => Did not return data
AppID 423 => Did not return data
AppID 424 => Did not return data
AppID 425 => Did not return data
AppID 426 => Did not return data
AppID 427 => Did not return data
AppID 428 => Did not return data
AppID 429 => Did not return data
AppID 430 => Did not return data
AppID 431 => Did not return data
AppID 432 => Did not return data
AppID 433 => Did not return data
AppID 434 => Did not return data
AppID 435 => Did not return data
AppID 436 => Did not return data
AppID 437 => Did not return data
AppID 438 => Did not return data
AppID 439 => Did not return data
AppID 441 => Did not return data
AppID 442 => Did not return data
AppID 443 => Did not return data
AppID 444 => Did not return data
AppID 445 => Did not return data
AppID 446 => Did not return data
AppID 447 => Did not return data
AppID 448 => Did not return data
AppID 449 => Did not return data
Downloading header image for AppID 420
Downloading header image for AppID 440
```

#### Notes

This utilizes the [`appdetails`](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI#appdetails), unofficial Steam Storefront API. With that bit of knowledge, that means that if Valve modifies it they probably aren't going to announce it ahead of time. It passes the `basic` filter, to reduce the amount of data that is returned (the `header_image` is part of this filter).

You could improve performance by passing a comma separated string of appids to the `base_url`. In general, Valve allows 100 at a time in these types of API calls. I haven't tested that with this specific call. If you do this, you will have to iterate through the response to check each returned application.

Comment: comma seperated appIds are no longer supported. each appId should be requested on it's own

Comment: It already requested each app individually. The items in the list are not all send as one request. They are sent one at a time

Comment: I know. i was referring to the `notes` part of this answer